# Templates in shared apps

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two django projects that share some common apps,
this is my structure:

- prj_1
- prj_2
- common_apps

From prj_1 and prj_2 I use the common apps and I'd like to render these apps with different templates.
How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the following directory structure:

```
common_apps
    app1
        templates
            app1
                # default templates for common app live here
prj_1
    templates
        app1
            # overridden templates for app1 live here (using same file name)
```

This isn't clearly spelled out in the docs in one place, but your `prj_1` templates will override `common_apps` because the [default setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-loaders) in Django looks like:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

...and your typical Django settings file will have something like this:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
    # where PROJECT_ROOT is absolute path to prj_1/
)
```

...which means when looking for say 'app1/base.html' the `filesystem.Loader` will get called first and will find any overridden templates in `prj_1` so `app_directories.Loader` won't get called.

Some info here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates